# linux - extracting some information out of line

Tags: linux, awk, sed

i have a file with many rows that have the format of:

> some-text several-digits some-other-text

e.g.

> Your number is 123456789 and you are blue
>
> your dad number is 987654321 and he is green since 1970.

I need to extract only the numbers that have 9 digits out of this file.

Can sed / awk / anything else help me here?

Thank

Comment: `grep -oE "\<[0-9]{9}\>" file` Why not with `grep`?

Comment: Yes, sed/awk/anything can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `grep` solution in your comments might be the simplest approach.

If you want to do it with sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(\b[0-9]\{9\}\b\).*/\1/p' file
```

Or a bit more readable using ERE:

```
sed -nE 's/.*(\b[0-9]{9}\b).*/\1/p' file
```